# I can't find the path where an image was saved

Tags: android, internal-storage

Im trying to save a profile photo, but when I use the save image code I got (i got almost the same example everywhere on the internet), I don't really know where the image is getting stored.

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap image) {
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream("BecityAvatar.png");
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, I want to store the image so when the profile launches and the layout is loaded, if there is an image stored as the avatar, it loads itself onto the imageview from the layout. If there isn't, nothing will happen. I don't really know where the images will get stored when I save them. Any help or tips will be appreciated.

Comment: current working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with:

```
out = new FileOutputStream("BecityAvatar.png");
```

this way you are creating a `FileOutputStream`, that *points* to   `/`, and your application has not right to write there. For instance

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "BecityAvatar.png")
out = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

to use `getFilesDir()`, you need a context